# Find all possible histories/paths of a deterministic process/procedurally generated graph?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, stochastic-processes, recurrence-relations

Let's say I have some weird breeds of cat and dog. After one generation, 1 cat gives 1 dog, but 1 dog gives 1 cat and 1 dog.

Say I start with 1 cat and 1 dog, so $G_1  = \{c_1 + d_1\}$. Then, $G_2 = \{c_1d_2 + d_1c_2 + d_1d_2\}$, $G_3 = \{c_1d_2c_3 + c_1d_2d_3 + d_1c_2d_3 + d_1d_2c_3 + d_1d_2d_3\}$ (I think using "$+$" makes it easier for notation than "$,$", because we can use the $\sum$ symbol, but feel free to use whatever you like.)

My question is simply: How do I find $G_n$?

I think the problem can be generalized into "finding all paths" on a graph if we consider cat and dog to be turning left or right. Also, we can find the number of cats and dogs $C_n$ and $D_n$ by:

$$C_n = D_{n-1} \\ D_n = C_{n-1}+ D_{n-1}$$

and see that $C_n$ and $D_n$ are just Fibonacci numbers, but I still got no clue how to find all their histories.

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of answer are you expecting here? A computer program to write down the entirety of $G_n$? A set theoretic description of the histories in $G_n$?

Comment: Yes, a set-theoretic description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's ignore the subscripts in the history, since they are the same for each. A history in $G_n$ is then just a string of symbols $s_1,s_2,\dots,s_n$, where each $s_i\in \{c,d\}$ for each $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$. Since a cat cannot give birth to a cat, there cannot be any adjacent symbols in a history which are both $c$. This is the only restriction. Therefore,
$$
G_n=\{s_1,s_2,\dots,s_n\mid \forall i\in [n],\,s_i\in \{c,d\},\;\;\forall i\in [n-1],\, s_is_{i+1}\neq cc\}
$$
Here I am using the notation $[n]:= \{1,\dots,n\}$ to shorten the notation.